# Hide the update button from edit view in wordpress custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript

Actually I'm trying to hide update button from edit view.bellow code is working for me.But the thing is when i update other than this particular post type(**book**)it will not redirect to same edit view.it's redirect to empty page

```
function hide_edit_book_update(){ ?>
  <style type="text/css">
   .post-type-book #publishing-action {display:none;}
  </style><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hide_edit_book_update' );
```

Comment: Have you added any other code? This could would not cause your issue. Something else is affecting the update of other post types. It's not this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes it's ok now.But now can't publish new custom post(book).i think publish and update button are same. display value only diffrent **<div id="publishing-action">
<span class="spinner"></span>
   <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="Update">
  <input name="save" type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" id="publish" value="Update">
  </div>**

Comment: need to know any identifier to differentiate this both(**add new**post and **edit** post)

Comment: They are the same button. What’s the ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer.

```
 function hide_edit_book_update(){ ?>
  <style type="text/css">
   .post-php.post-type-book #publishing-action {display:none;}
  </style><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hide_edit_book_update' );
```

**add new** post and **edit** post we can differentiate from **post-php** and **php-new-php** css class